# Close the TK window using Ruby

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

I am new to Ruby. I was able to create a simple window with simple ok/cancel buttons with the following code and it works:

```
require 'tk'

root = TkRoot.new
root.title = "Window"

msgBox = Tk.messageBox(
  'type'    => "okcancel",  
  'icon'    => "info", 
  'title'   => "Framework",
  'message' => "This is message"
)
Tk.mainloop #No operation is performed until closing the TK window
Tk.destroy()
Tk.exit()
```

Though I can close the window manually, I can't make the window close programmatically. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

TK is library , you should not make TK.destroy , since root is the object of the TkRoot , it should be as below:

```
root.destroy()
```

Hope this answer helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Window.destroy` or `Window.iconify`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using Ruby 2.2.5 (with Tk 8.5.12) on Windows 7:

```rb
require 'tk'

root = TkRoot.new
root.title = "Window"

msgBox = Tk.messageBox(
  'type'    => "okcancel",  
  'icon'    => "info", 
  'title'   => "Framework",
  'message' => "This is message"
)
if 'ok' == msgBox
  root.destroy
  Kernel.exit
end
Tk.mainloop
```

The TkDocs tutorial section [Creating and Destroying Windows](http://tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html#createdestroy) simply says "[I]f you happen to destroy the root window[, this] will...end your application." However, in order to avoid getting a `Segmentation fault`, I needed to add `Kernel.exit`.